# python - convert pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.QuarterEnd to integer

Tags: python, pandas, tslib

I have two dates:

```
a = (pd.to_datetime(20191231, format='%Y%m%d') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)).to_period('Q')
b = (pd.Timestamp(str(2020) + '-' + str(4 * 3)) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)).to_period('Q')
```

I calculated their difference:

```
c = a - b
```

The type of `c` is still `pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.QuarterEnd`. Is there a way I can convert `c` to integer (# of quarter difference)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `n` attribute from [`QuarterEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd.html) to get the expected result:

```py
>>> c = a - b
>>> c.n
-4
```

Comment: Thank you @tlentali. More of a follow up question: if I have a pandas series of QuarterEnd, would there be a similar way to convert it to a pandas series of integer? I know I can use a for loop to do it but I feel there is better way to do so.

Comment: I think I can just use apply(lambda) to do it. Thank you @tlentali.